# Print angular element tag-name inside linking function

Tags: angularjs

Jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/23009/).

Inside my directive's linking function, i am trying to print the directive element's tag name as,

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          element.append('<hr>you know, my tag name is ' + element.tagName)

         }
    }
})
```

It prints `undefined` whereas i expect the directive's tag name `my-directive` to be printed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use this element[0].tagName

Comment: `element[0].tagName` is correct although `element` is not an array.

Answer (score 1):

`TagName` is a HTML DOM property, not a jQuery attribute. Change `element.tagName` to `element[0].tagName`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways.

```
element.append('<hr>you know my tag name is ' + element.prop("tagName"))

OR

element.append('<hr>you know, my tag name is ' + element[0].tagName)
```